# Displaying a list (Python) on Flask rendered html template - page renders empty

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to display data that I've read from a csv file into a list, on a Flask rendered html template. For some reason, the html page (/sheet) is completely empty. Any help would be appreciated! Below is the relevant code.

This is the method (in Python) that reads the csv file and tries to open the webpage:

```
@app.route("/sheet", methods=["GET"])
def get_sheet():
file = open("survey.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
registrations = list(reader)
return render_template("sheet.html", registrations=registrations)
```

This is the code in the sheet.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Total registrations</h1>
<ul>
{% for registration in registrations %}
<li>{{ registration[0] }} {{ registration[1] }} {{ registration[2] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">

        <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/ -->
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <title>Survey</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/ -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand mb-1 h1" href="/">Survey</a>
            <button aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-target="#navbarNav" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/form">Form</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/sheet">Sheet</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#containers -->
        <main class="container-fluid p-5">
            {% block main %}{% endblock %}
        </main>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Completely empty, ie not even the "Total registrations" header? And show your layout.html.

Comment: I think you should start with debugging your API. Does Flask even receive your request? Does it do what it is supposed to do (read the csv file, render the template)? Does it return empty or non-empty page?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Indeed completely empty, not even the header "Total registrations", but the URL is definitely changed to /sheet.

Comment: @ValeriySavchenko - The csv file is definitely read into the list, that much a checked by printing the list to the console. The problem is that page that's rendered is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the layout.html file, you did not defined a block body. You have only `{% block main %}{% endblock %}`.

So to fix the issue, you need to replace `{% block body %}` by `{% block main %}` in the sheet.html file.

The sheet.html will be similar to this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block main %}
<h1>Total registrations</h1>
<ul>
{% for registration in registrations %}
<li>{{ registration[0] }} {{ registration[1] }} {{ registration[2] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```